# Weblogic JDBC query gets stuck

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a WebLogic server and a basic EJB module, with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, communicating with a Postgres database. I also have a web application on a different managed server on the same domain.

When I'm trying to start a request to the database, through a Spring Data repository, I see from the logs that the method on the repository was called, but the sequence got stuck at that point. I also suspect from the database logs that no SQL request ever reached the database.

I see no error, other than an exception saying that a thread on the web application got stuck (not on the EJB module, which is supposed to send the actual request).

It's not a long lasting request probably since it has been going on for hours maybe, while from pgAdmin, I could request the tables in under a second.

I think I found the reason. I thought I managed to get rid of an exception, but it seems like I just hid it. The exception is this: 
`Exception Description: Error binding to externally managed transaction`
`Internal Exception: weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction`. The stacktrace is not in the logs for some reason.

In another log file (I'm getting even more confused at this point) I fount a stacktrace with an undescriptive exception:

```
 <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager$SearchKey.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:2401)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInPairedConnTable(ConnectionManager.java:2338)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInPairedConnTable(ConnectionManager.java:2326)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.sendMsg(ConnectionManager.java:611)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.send(RJVMImpl.java:1168)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

This is right after when the repository method is called

Comment: Use jstack to find out where the active threads are. It is cheap, so you could even do that in production. If it is a test system you could also enable SQL logging, that will let you see what Hibernate tries to send to the database.

Comment: I would disable XA for the JDBC driver and give it a try. Using XA driver means it starts the request as a new transaction and PG DB might not be expecting a transactional request.. Also check the driver you are using if you need XA.

Comment: Does this mean that I should untick "support global transaction" checkbox as well?